# Replace default task for Less with a Gulp task

Tags: sass, gulp, less

I have downloaded AngularJS setup for PhoneGap from this [tutorial](http://mobileangularui.com/blog/using-the-generator/).

Now I would like to use Sass instead of Less (since that's what I'm using in the project I am porting to PhoneGap). The default Less task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.less.src).pipe(less({
    paths: config.less.paths.map(function(p){
      return path.resolve(__dirname, p);
    })
  }))
  .pipe(mobilizer('app.css', {
    'app.css': {
      hover: 'exclude',
      screens: ['0px']
    },
    'hover.css': {
      hover: 'only',
      screens: ['0px']
    }
  }))
  .pipe(cssmin())
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.dest, 'css')));
});
```

I've tried this Gulp task for Sass:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/css/main.scss')
  .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css/'));
});
```

Nothing seems to be happening (cannot see a newly generated `main.scss` file). Could someone help (I haven't been using Gulp before as you can probably guess. I've read through [this](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) though..)

UPDATE:
I am not actually replacing the Less task, I am just adding another task for Sass.

UPDATE 2:
I am calling the Sass task in here

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  if(typeof config.server === 'object') {
    gulp.watch([config.dest + '/**/*'], ['livereload']);
  }
  gulp.watch(['./src/html/**/*'], ['html']);
  gulp.watch(['./src/sass/css/*'], ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['./src/js/**/*', './src/templates/**/*', config.vendor.js], ['js']);
  gulp.watch(['./src/images/**/*'], ['images']);
});
```

However the problem seems to be that it's not executed.

UPDATE 3:
Here's the build phase code

```
gulp.task('build', function(done) {
  var tasks = ['html', 'fonts', 'images', 'sass', 'js'];
  seq('clean', tasks, done);
});
```

Comment: Two possibilities: (1) Your `sass` task doesn't actually run, because you're not calling it (2) Your path is wrong.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung from where would I be calling it?

Comment: Dunno. Command line? Gulpfile? You tell me.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung see update 2 for how I am calling it... but it doesn't do anything

Comment: It's a watch. It'll only do something if you change the file.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung sorry. now updated with the build as well

Answer (score 0):

Your path is absolute, not relative. Don't forget the *dots* ;)

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('./src/sass/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css/'));
});
```

Comment: doesn't make a difference to the result